# Is there a elegant way to include javascript file in custom directive javascript file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Custom directive <my-directive-a> uses another custom directive <my-directive-b> inside it. In main.html, only <my-directive-a> is used. But I should include myDirectiveB.js (defining <my-directive-b>) in main.html. Is there an elegant way to remove this ? I want to include myDirectiveB.js in myDirectiveA.js not in main.html.

main.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <my-directive-a>
    </my-directive-a>

    <script src='/angularjs/shared/myDirectiveA.js'></script>

    <!-- I want to remove following one line -->
    <script src='/angularjs/shared/myDirectiveB.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myDirectiveA.js

```
...
.directive("myDirectiveA", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',           
        template: '<div><my-directive-b></my-directive-b></div>' 
    }
});
```

myDirectiveB.js

```
...
.directive("myDirectiveB", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',           
        template: '<div>my directive b</div>' 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for something like `@import` which is available in css. But unfortunately that is not available

But you are using jQuery can try

```
$.getScript('fileName',function(){
 //Rest of Code
})
```

otherwise with pure JS

```
var crScript = document.createElement('script');
   crScript.src ="file Location";
   document.whereYouWantToAppend.apendChild(crScript);
```